# Why Linux command dmidecode when use in exec returns nothing?

Tags: php, linux, terminal, debian, exec

If run command "dmidecode -s processor-frequency" in the terminal, it displays information: 2000 MHz.
But when I run a PHP script:

```
exec("dmidecode -s processor-frequency", $output);
print_r($output);
```

It returns nothing.

Update:
Command in example returns 1 row. In this case we can use **exec**.
Maybe instead of **dmidecode** to use this application path?
But what is the path?

Answer (score 0):

[`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)'s `$output` contains only the last line  from the result:

> The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the `passthru()` function.

If you want to capture full output, use [`passthru`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) or [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

**`passthru`**

```
$command = "dmidecode -s processor-frequency";
passthru($command, $output);
echo $output;
```

**`proc_open`**

```
$command = "dmidecode -s processor-frequency";
$desc = [ 1 => ['pipe', 'w'], 2 => ['pipe', 'w'] ];
$proc = proc_open($command, $desc, $pipes);

if (!is_resource($proc)) {
  fprintf(STDERR, "command failed: $command\n");
  exit(1);
}

if ($output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1])) {
  fprintf(STDOUT, "STDOUT: %s\n", $output);
}

if ($error = stream_get_contents($pipes[2])) {
  fprintf(STDERR, "STDERR: %s\n", $error);
}

fclose($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[2]);

proc_close($proc);
```

Comment: @NazarVozniy, well, then the command returns `error 127` string. If that's not what you've expected, then the issue should be in the command itself. I've just shown how to capture `stdout` and `stderr`.